# How to navigate to another fiori application using overview page application card?

Tags: navigation, sap-fiori

I am trying to navigate to another **`Fiori`** app by clicking the analytical card header in overview page application but its giving me error

> "NavigationHandler.isIntentSupported.Failed".

Can anyone tell me steps for navigation?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/530f9e6f66104d5888ade79b5cf417e0) it says:
“The preferred way to configure intent based navigation is to use “DataFieldForIntentBasedNavigation”.
However, in the case of navigation to a specific application route that is not configured as target mapping, 
you can also use “DataFieldWithUrl” to construct the specific application route. 
The overview page will identify that this is an intent based navigation and open the application in the relevant context, in the same tab.”

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227254/how-to-navigate-from-fiori-overview-page-ovp) might also  be helpful.

Comment: I used the code from given link but it didn't work. 
Its still showing error  
"Navigation to the application not supported".

Comment: Is your Overview Page running in a Launchpad where the other apps are also running?

Comment: I have found the issue , it is with Action field in which I am getting the names of function imports and when I tried to pass the name of function import it concatenate the path of service which stops the navigation.

Answer (score -1):

Below is my manifest.json

```
   {
        "_version": "1.5.0",
        "start_url": "start.html",
        "sap.app": {
            "id": "Overview",
            "type": "application",
            "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
            "applicationVersion": {
                "version": "1.2.2"
            },
            "title": "{{app_title}}",
            "description": "{{app_description}}",
            "ach": "sap",
            "resources": "resources.json",
            "dataSources": {
                "OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV": {
                    "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/ibscms/OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV/",
                    "type": "OData",
                    "settings": {
                        "localUri": "localService/OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV/metadata.xml",
                        "annotations": ["dmAnnot"]
                    }
                },
                "dmAnnot": {
                    "type": "ODataAnnotation",
                    "uri": "localService/OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV/dmAnnot.xml",
                    "settings": {
                        "localUri": "localService/OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV/dmAnnot.xml"
                    }
                }
            },
            "sourceTemplate": {
                "id": "OVP.cardtemplate",
                "version": "0.0.0"
            },
            "crossNavigation": {
                "inbounds": {}
            }
        },
        "sap.ui": {
            "technology": "UI5",
            "icons": {
                "icon": ""
            },
            "deviceTypes": {
                "desktop": true,
                "tablet": true,
                "phone": true
            },
            "supportedThemes": ["sap_hcb", "sap_belize"]
        },
        "sap.ui5": {
            "dependencies": {
                "minUI5Version": "1.32.0",
                "libs": {
                    "sap.ui.core": {},
                    "sap.m": {},
                    "sap.ui.layout": {},
                    "sap.f": {},
                    "sap.ushell": {},
                    "sap.collaboration": {},
                    "sap.ui.comp": {},
                    "sap.uxap": {},
                    "sap.ovp": {}
                }
            },
            "models": {
                "i18n": {
                    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                    "uri": "i18n/i18n.properties"
                },
                "OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV": {
                    "dataSource": "OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV",
                    "settings": {}
                },
                "@i18n": {
                    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                    "uri": "i18n/i18n.properties"
                }
            },
            "extends": {
                "extensions": {}
            },
            "contentDensities": {
                "compact": true,
                "cozy": true
            }
        },
        "sap.ovp": {
            "globalFilterModel": "OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV",
            "globalFilterEntityType": "DmHeader",
            "cards": {
                "Overview_card00": {
                    "model": "OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV",
                    "template": "sap.ovp.cards.table",
                    "settings": {
                        "title": "{{Overview_card00_title}}",
                        "entitySet": "DmCoSet",
                        "addODataSelect": "false",
                        "selectionAnnotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.SelectionVariant#artistS",
                        "annotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem#artistD",
                        "identificationAnnotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.Identification#bar"
                    }
                },
                "Overview_card02": {
                    "model": "OVERVIEWPAGE_SRV",
                    "template": "sap.ovp.cards.charts.analytical",
                    "settings": {
                        "title": "{{Overview_card02_title}}",
                        "entitySet": "DmCostSet",
                        "selectionAnnotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.SelectionVariant#costFilter",
                        "dataPointAnnotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataPoint#chartD",                   "chartAnnotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.Chart#chart1",
                        "identificationAnnotationPath": "com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.Identification#bar",
                        "navigation": "dataPointNav"
                    }
                }

            }
        },
        "sap.platform.hcp": {
            "uri": "webapp",
            "_version": "1.1.0"
        }
    }
```